# How to check if self.navigationController is nil

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, gdb, debugging

In the following code, I am able to check with the debugger the values of self and childView.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES];
```

[image]

However, I am not able to see the value of self.navigationController. How can I check if it is nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the line:

```
UINavigationController* navController = self.navigationController;
```

And then set a breakpoint, or whatever else you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because `navigationController` is a property, so you can't just examine it; you would have to send the property's owner a getter message. In the debugger, that's pretty expensive, especially if it crashes or otherwise fails, plus it could always have side effects (e.g., faulting in a Core Data object, lazy-loading something, or changing some state in another ivar), so the debugger will not do this casually.

You must explicitly request the message using the Debugger Console:

```
po [self navigationController]
```

(I don't know whether it will let you use property-access syntax there. There's no difference between them, which is the root of the problem: A property access *is* an Objective-C message, which, as I described above, is why the debugger won't do one unless you specifically tell it to.)

Answer (score 1):

You could always just do something like `(self.navigationController == nil)`.